# Swift Storyboard - Centring an Icon and multi-line text horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to create an Android-esque Snackbar.  All the behaviour is correct but I am left with a layout issue.  I have actually broken this out into a test app to simplify things a bit.

[image]

The bar is pinned to the bottom of the view and contains an Icon (UIImageView) along with some text (UILabel).  This text can be up to 2 lines max.

For example, it should be able to exand out like this:-

[image]

However to further complicate things, i need it so that the icon and text are centred within the red bar and then spread out from the centre until such point that it needs to wrap.  Note that there is a padding to the start of the icon and end of the text to prevent it touching the sides.  An example of centred content would be..

[image]

I haven't been able to get the correct layout.  I think the issue has been trying to centre the two items whilst simultaneously conforming to a width that doesn't exceed the edge bounds, causing a constraint conflict.  I have also tried embedding the icon and label in a horizontal stack view but couldn't seem to find the correct fill option whilst centring everything.

I have even tried using NSAttributed string and adding the image to the text itself but when the text wrapped, the icon was being resized and/or misplaced.

As you can see, i have been doing this in Storyboard but i am more than happy to do this programmatically if it serves this purpose better.

Comment: does the red view need to resize due to label height? or the height is fixed?

Comment: The red container view has a fixed height.  The text can have a maximum of two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Created this [Demo](https://github.com/ShKhan9/ExpandView)  for reference , it's a simple task of making  a nested view inside the red view with a centerX constraint of priority 1000 and a leading constraint with 999 priority

[image]

Now you have this effect

[image]

Comment: I think he said the red bar has a fixed height though

Comment: Thanks, i believe this is what i need or has at least nudged me in the right direction.  The bar is fixed height though and the content (image and label) need to be centred vertically as well.

Comment: @henrik-dmg - teh_raab i made the height flexible you can add a fixed height if you need to also  making the content centered vertically is a matter of equal top and bottom constants

Comment: @teh_raab I see. In my opinion, using a `UIStackView` is the nicer option as it achieves the same effect with way less constraints that you need to set yourself. But that's just my personal taste

Comment: @henrik-dmg using stackview will make less constraints between the image and the label but the idea of setting outer constraints will be the same